# Is every program essentially just a really big number?

Tags: binary

If every program is just made up of 0s and 1s, then technically every program is just a #, right?

For example, 647364981374813780414810937401 could technically be decimal code that in binary is the "Hello, World" program in C or whatever.

Is this correct?

Comment: All programs are compiled down to bytecode (either at build time or runtime) that the CPU understands. Those bytes are instructions and data that are fed to the CPU and are numbers. So, to answer your question, every program eventually gets converted to a string of numbers before it is fed to the CPU.

Comment: ...and the multiple numbers could be understood as one big number, so yes, it´s true.

Comment: Yes indeed. The computer memory itself is just one huge binary number, and the computer is a function that transposes that number (state) into another number (state).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you consider a program it's storage representation, it seems fair to say that program is nothing more than a very large number(so large that we can't even comprehend it).

But this number does nothing and means nothing by itself. It requires, in the very least, highly specific hardware that knows what to do with it, and only in conjunction with this will the number provide any, and, the expected behavior.

So all the possible representations of things we have inside computer systems(digital), meaning all data, is nothing but a very large number, whose first and large digit you can arbitrarily assign according to the behavior/meaning intended.

You can say that the entire state of your computer, is nothing but a very large number that starts at the first bit in your hard drive and ends in the last. That number only has meaning though, with the hardware to interpret it(and the other smaller numbers, or components of that number which represent the programs).

You could even say, that if it is possible to digitally simulate the universe, then the entire state of the universe would be a single number. Something would need to be there to interpret that number and make the next state though.

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this a bit lately. I suppose it's an example of reductionism, or the reductionist fallacy. (Is that even a thing?)

In his book, *Goedel, Escher, Bach*, Douglas Hoffstadter talks about the different 'layers' of information in a computer system.

Comment: I hope he knew more about information systems that he did about music. I only read the Bach part years ago but his ideas about it were trivial in the extreme.